# module not found markupsafe

Tags: python, flask, pip, python-3.6

I create a virtual env:

```
> virtualenv -p python3 spectap
```

I activate it and install packages from requirements.txt in it:

```
> . spectap/bin/activate
> pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Running my flask app in debug mode gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/app4/app/spectap/bin/flask", line 5, in <module>
    from flask.cli import main
  File "/home/ec2-user/app4/app/spectap/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from markupsafe import escape
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe'
```

I install `markupsafe`:

```
(spectap) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-23-155 app]$ pip3 install MarkupSafe==2.0.1
Collecting MarkupSafe==2.0.1
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (30 kB)
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe
  WARNING: Value for scheme.purelib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
  distutils: /home/ec2-user/app4/app/spectap/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
  sysconfig: /home/ec2-user/app4/app/spectap/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  WARNING: Additional context:
  user = False
  home = None
  root = None
  prefix = None
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.0.1
```

After installation in my virtual env, I run `pip show markupsafe` but it still does not seem to find the package:

```
(spectap) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-23-155 app]$ pip3 show markupsafe
WARNING: Package(s) not found: markupsafe
```

Also re-running my flask app still shows the `no module named markupsafe` error.

What am I missing?

P.S. Here is what the path variable looks like from inside the virtual environment:

```
(spectap) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-23-155 app]$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', 
 '/home/ec2-user/app5/app/spectap/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', 
 '/home/ec2-user/app5/app/spectap/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 
 '/home/ec2-user/app5/app/spectap/lib64/python3.6', 
 '/home/ec2-user/app5/app/spectap/lib/python3.6', 
 '/home/ec2-user/app5/app/spectap/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', 
 '/home/ec2-user/app5/app/spectap/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 
 '/home/ec2-user/app5/app/spectap/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
 '/home/ec2-user/app5/app/spectap/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', 
 '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6']
```

Comment: Show us the exact command you are using to run the flask app.

Comment: @JohnGordon - "flask run" from a terminal

Comment: Well, that's probably the issue -- the venv does not contain its own `flask` command, so it defaults to the normal one on the system.

Comment: @JohnGordon I switched to using "python app.py" to run the flask app.. but get the same issue.

Comment: Inside your virtual env, run this command and show us the output `pip3 show markupsafe`

Comment: Also run this command and show the output `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

Comment: @JohnGordon added all the to the post above.. after a successful install, it still cannot find the package while running "pip3 show". See above..

Comment: Hmm.  Perhaps the capitalization is significant?  Please try `pip3 show MarkupSafe`

Comment: @JohnGordon -- nah, that doesn't work either.. btw - thank you for all the help so far BTW.

Comment: You said you installed it with pip3 in the question, and you showed the results.  I'm puzzled why pip3 would say it's not installed.  Are you running this in the same virtual env where it was installed earlier?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes - that's exactly what's intriguing me.. and yes it's the same virtual env.

Comment: If you install it again, what happens?

Comment: Did you tear down the virtual env and recreate it with the same name?  Or it is literally the exact same one from when you installed markupsafe before?

Comment: @JohnGordon - no i did not tear down and recreate.. anyways, since I was not getting further so decided to kill that ec2 instance, create a new one, upgraded my python and pip to the latest versions and got everything to work. Yes - I still don't know what was wrong but hey, at least I can move forward now. Thank you for trying to help on this!